# Access database insert is not succesful

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

I'm trying to insert some data from my textboxes into a MS Access database.

The code runs successfully, but the new data does not appear in the database.

All data types or Shorttext

```
try
{
    OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=dsms.accdb");
    connection.Open();
      string Dcode = textDcode.Text;
      string Dname = textDname.Text;
      string Units = textDunit.Text;
      string Price = textDbuyp.Text;
      string BPrice = textDsellp.Text;
      string Category = textDcategory.Text;

      string my_query = "INSERT INTO Drugs(Dcode, Dname, Units, Price, BPrice, Category)VALUES('"+Dcode+"','"+Dname+"','"+Units+"','"+Price+"','"+BPrice+"','"+Category+"')";

      OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(my_query, connection);
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

      MessageBox.Show("Data saved successfully");
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
      MessageBox.Show("Failed due to " + ex.Message);
  }
  finally
  {
      connection.Close();
  }
```

Comment: No errors? Are you sure? Do any of these variables have a single quote in them?

Comment: You are vulnerable  to *SQL Injection* . Moreover, how do you know data not inserted? are you checking against the right DB/Table?

Comment: @JNevill: To be fair, INSERT does not throw a lot of exceptions. And he does at least expose the message. So it is not a total sin of Exception Handling.

Comment: @JNevill
Yes I'm sure not even Exception Error

Comment: @Rahul
SQL injection doesn't matter right now. I did check the records

Comment: @ArminMalek: How sure are you? Access is more like teh Officer Approxmiation of the Database and DBMS. It does not behave anything like proper ones. It could well be using a previously read status and other things.

Comment: The code looks fine (apart from  connection definition should be outside the try block), I would check what is being inserted into the table and see if the my_query string is malformed. Try setting all the string variables to a default value and see if they insert.

Comment: There is something like SQL profiler to trace incoming queries in SQL server not sure if there is something like that on AccessDB .Perhaps you could try following steps for AccessDB if your application connects to a database using ODBC and a registered data connection. go to Administrative Tools (Control Panel or even Start Menu if they are displayed), you can find an "Data sources (ODBC)" applet. Start it and click on "Tracing" tab

Comment: Can you add the full path to the database?

Comment: I seriously doubt, that the fields `Units, Price` are Text. If they are, change them to a number data type as Currency at the soonest.

Answer (score 0):

1) Create the insert statement with real values.
For this put a break ponit in the fields

```
  string Dcode = textDcode.Text;
  string Dname = textDname.Text;
  string Units = textDunit.Text;
  string Price = textDbuyp.Text;
  string BPrice = textDsellp.Text;
  string Category = textDcategory.Text;
```

Example:

```
INSERT INTO Drugs(Dcode, Dname, Units, Price, BPrice, Category)VALUES('0001','nombre A','3','3454545','2453245','categoria A')
```

and with these values ​​build your senetence manually. Run it separately in your database engine.

2) Confirm that you are correctly inserting into the table from the database console.

3) When you have the sentence inserted correctly, set it from the c # code and try to insert from c #.
Example:

```
 string my_query = "INSERT INTO Drugs(Dcode, Dname, Units, Price, BPrice, Category)VALUES('0001','nombre A','3','3454545','2453245','categoria A')";
```

4) when the insert from c # works replace the values ​​of the fields with the variables.
Example:

```
 string my_query = String.Format("INSERT INTO Drugs(Dcode, Dname, Units, Price, BPrice, Category)VALUES('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}','{5}')",Dname, Units, Price, BPrice, Category) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to disconnect and connect ur Microsoft Access Database, then check data again